# jquery each loop through all the element after the clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

this is the razor code of the elements that will be generated

```
    @{  k = 0; }; 
    @foreach (var item in Model.Where(q=>q.isOrginal==true))
    {          
        <tr>
            <td>Starting Time</td>
            <td>                    
                @Html.Hidden("[" + i + "].isOrginal", true)
                @Html.DropDownList("[" + i + "].StartingTime", new SelectList(ViewBag.StartingTime, "Value", "Text", item.StartingTime.ToString()), new { @class = "no-select dropdown", data_id= @k,id="starting-true" + @k, data_val="true" })               
            </td>
            <td>Ending Time</td>
            <td>                 
                @Html.DropDownList("[" + i + "].EndingTime", new SelectList(ViewBag.EndingTime, "Value", "Text", item.EndingTime.ToString()), new { @class = "no-select dropdown", data_id = @k,id = "ending-true" + @k, data_val = "true" })                 
            </td>
            <td>Charges</td>
            <td>                
                @Html.TextBox("[" + i + "].Charges", item.Charges, new { @class = "original", data_id = @k, id = "original-false" + @k })
            </td>
        </tr>
        i++;
        k++;
    }
```

this is the jquery code so far

```
$(document).on('change', '.dropdown', function (e)
{         

                $('.dropdown').each(function (i, obj) {

                    var ii = $(obj).attr("data-val");
                    if (ii == "true") {
                        console.log(ii);
                    }

                });  
});
```

suppose there are 8 dropdown generated on the page

```
st     en
st     en
st     en 
st     en
```

whichever dropdown i onchanges i want to start loop from the next dropdown to the last. if it is the last i don't want to loop through anything. how can i achieve this?

Comment: Since your dropdowns are in `tr` tags you need is first select the parent `tr` of the current dropdown and then select all the dropdowns that are part of the `tr` that is after this parent `tr`. Like  `$(this).closest('tr')..nextAll().find('.dropdown').each...`

Comment: Do you mean the next dropdownlist in the same `<tr>` element (e.g. if you select one of the `StartingTime` - it will start at `EndingTime`, or do you mean starting at the first dropdownlist in the next `<tr>` element

Comment: if i select startingtime ,start the loop from the ending time in the same tr.

Comment: if i select endingtime start the loop from the starting time in the next tr

Answer (score 0):

Try below code (not tested as per your scenario but should work)

```
$(".dropdown").on("change",function(e){ 
  var nextdps = $(this).nextAll(".dropdown");
  if(!nextdps){
   nextdps = [];
  }

  var nextTrs = $(this).parents("tr").nextAll("tr");

  $.each(nextTrs,function(i,elm){
        var trDps= $(elm).find(".dropdown"); 
      if(trDps){
      nextdps.push(trDps);
      }
  });


   $.each(nextdps,function(i,elm){
        var ii = $(elm).attr("data-val");
      if (ii == "true") {
        console.log(ii);
      }  
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way. I changed `change` event to `click` so you can click on any word and see the following highlighted in `red`.

This way you can have dropdowns anywhere in your code, as long as the have their id set.

```js
var id;

$(document).on('click', '.dropdown', function(e)
{ 
  id = $(this).attr('id').split('dropdown').pop();
  id = parseInt( id );
  $('.dropdown').removeClass('red');
  $('.dropdown').each( check );
});


function check( index ) 
{
  if ( id == $('.dropdown').length -1 ) { return }
  if ( index <= id ) { return }
  $('.dropdown').get(index).classList.add('red');
  // Do whatever you want here with `index`
}
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown0">Zero</div>
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown1">One</div>
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown2">Two</div>
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown3">Three</div>
<div class="dropdown" id="dropdown4">Four</div>
```